# How to handle JTextField value retainment without add it into a Dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, jsplitpane

Ok, based on this link [JTextField in JDialog retaining value after dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691835/jtextfield-in-jdialog-retaining-value-after-dispose) Im aware now why my TextField is retainning its value, but looking to my code I dont know how to handle this.

[image]

My textfield is inside my Main Pane, which is inside a JSplitPane. As left component I have A JTree and as Right Component I have the Main Pane. The SplitPane goes inside the Dialog so, does anyone has a clue how can I handle this? How can I take the value of the TextField after dispose it and open again? I cant simple add the textfield to the dialog, The only way I can see until now is somehow make a vector for the textfields

Comment: "How can I handle this?" is not a complete enough question for us to answer.  What is it you want to do, and what have you tried that hasn't worked as you expected?

Comment: I just want to take the value of the textfield. Quite simple. The problem ist that I cant do this until now cos the textfield isnt inside the dialog, its inside the pane, which is inside the dialog, I cant avoid to use the pane cos I need to it as a SplitPane to manage the setup of the software. For the first attempt the setup works fine, but after dispose it and open again the dialog is point to the last disposed textfield based on the link I've posted..I tryed nothing cos I wanna see if someone gives me a better Idea than handle this with a vector of JTextfield

Comment: _but looking to my code_ well, that's more than any of us can do right now :-) Without seeing code (best as an SSCCE) the question isn't answerable, so voting to close

Comment: "to take the value of the textfield.  Quite simple."  Except that "take the value of" is not a specific Swing operation.  Do you mean you want to obtain the value and use it outside the UI?  That would be my guess, but I hate answering based on guesses.

Comment: @kleopatra The description is pretty much clear than a version of SSCCE code cos the only thing you are gonna see from it is components addition and a simple ``getText()`` from the TextField, if you dont wanna help, so dont bother who is trying to and even vote down the question. Anyway I will find a solution my way and post here for u to see.

Comment: @rcook not sure if that is it, but the value is gonna be send to a file writer, from there stored in the setup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem declare the textfield as static:

```
//JTextField Declaration and Initialization 
static JTextField NODES_TEXT_FIELD = new JTextField();
```

After that catch the value of the TextField:

```
int  nodes = Integer.valueOf(NODES_TEXT_FIELD.getText());
```

In my case was an int value, switch yourself; After that clear the value of the textfield cos it will be stored since the component is static, if you dont do this after dispose the dialog and open again you will see the last value used.

```
NODES_TEXT_FIELD.setText("");
```

Special thanks to @kleopatra

Comment: if static is the solution, then there's something very suboptimal in your setup: you may need a reference to the field (in absense of a higher abstraction of your data), but nothing forces you to keep it _static_